# How do you load/store from/to an array of doubles with GNU C Vector Extensions?

Tags: c, gcc, x86, vectorization, simd

I'm using [GNU C Vector Extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html), not Intel's `_mm_*` intrinsics.

I want to do the same thing as Intel's `_m256_loadu_pd` intrinsic. Assigning the values one by one is slow: gcc produces code that has 4 load instructions, rather than one single `vmovupd` (which `_m256_loadu_pd` does generate).

```
typedef double vector __attribute__((vector_size(4 * sizeof(double))));

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    double a[4] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0};
    vector v;

    /* I currently do this */
    v[0] = a[0];
    v[1] = a[1];
    v[2] = a[2];
    v[3] = a[3];
}
```

I want something like this:

```
v = (vector)(a);
```

or

```
v = *((vector*)(a));
```

but neither work. The first fails with "can't convert value to a vector" while the second results in segfaults.

Comment: Choose one language. C and C++ are different language.

Comment: @Shravan40: The original question was tagged C and is asking about C, the C++ edit was by someone else (now reverted).

Comment: @dvhh: the code is fairly clearly not using C++ `vector` template notation and the title says 'C', not 'C++'.  I don't see why C++ is appropriate.  I assume that at one point it had both tags, but that seems to have been fixed.

Comment: If you want `memcpy`, just use `memcpy`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: does memcpy produce the efficient code wanted on your machine?

Comment: @dave If `memcpy`, given all the information, didn't produce the most efficient code on my machine, I'd use a better compiler/library/whatever. What possible excuse is there for not doing it the best way?

Comment: Unless your HW architecture supports 256-bit load/store operations, I don't see any reason to hope that the assignment operation of `v = a` (even if you somehow find the correct syntax for it) will be compiled into a single opcode. If it doesn't support 128-bit load/store operations either, then you may as well copy these 4 values one by one (as you are currently doing).

Comment: why don't just use `_m256_loadu_pd`?

Comment: @2501: IIRC, GNU C Vector Extension pointers are defined as `may_alias`.    At least the Intel intrinsic types (like `__m256d`) are defined that way in GNU C, so it's safe to mix vector loads/stores to an array of `double` with scalar loads/stores to the same array, and casting `double*` to `__m256d*`.  But anyway, that doesn't explain the segfault.  Failure to detect aliasing leads to loading bogus data, not segfaults (at least not directly.  Sure you could construct a case where something uses a stale or uninitialized pointer, but this isn't like that.)

Comment: @barakmanos: he *is* compiling for a target that supports 256b load/store operations; specifically x86 with AVX.  Even baseline x86-64 includes 128b SSE2.  (Most architectures these days have 128b SIMD vectors.  ARM, MIPS, PowerPC, and x86 all have more or less widely supported vector extensions.  256b vectors may be unique to x86, though.)

Comment: In this particular example, you could write directly `vector v = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0};`, although I expect this was just to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @PeterCordes may_alias is not necessary to let the types vector of double and double alias (just like array of double can alias double). `__m256d` is may_alias because the Intel specs want all the vector types of the same size to be compatible.

Answer (score 4):

update: I see you're using GNU C's native vector syntax, not Intel intrinsics.  Are you avoiding Intel intrinsics for portability to non-x86?  gcc currently does a bad job compiling code that uses GNU C vectors wider than the target machine supports.  (You'd hope that it would just use two 128b vectors and operate on each separately, but apparently it's worse than that.)

Anyway, **this answer shows how you can use Intel x86 intrinsics to load data into GNU C vector-syntax types**

---

First of all, looking at compiler output at less than `-O2` is a waste of time if you're trying to learn anything about what will compile to good code.  Your `main()` will optimize to just a `ret` at -O2.

Besides that, it's not totally surprising that you get bad asm from assigning elements of a vector one at a time.

---

Aside: normal people would call the type `v4df` (vector of 4 Double Float) or something, not `vector`, so they don't go insane when using it with C++ `std::vector`.  For single-precision, `v8sf`.  IIRC, gcc uses type names like this internally for `__m256d`.

On x86, Intel intrinsic types (like `__m256d`) are implemented on top of GNU C vector syntax (which is why you can do `v1 * v2` in GNU C instead of writing `_mm256_mul_pd(v1, v2)`).  You can convert freely from `__m256d` to `v4df`, like I've done here.

**I've wrapped both sane ways to do this in functions, so we can look at their asm**.  Notice how we're not loading from an array that we define inside the same function, so the compiler won't optimize it away.

I put them on the [Godbolt compiler explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g6,options:'-xc+-std%3Dgnu11+-Wall+-Wextra++-O3+-fverbose-asm+-march%3Dhaswell',source:'typedef+double+v4df+__attribute__((vector_size(4+*+sizeof(double))))%3B%0A%0A//+terrible+asm%0Av4df+load_4_doubles(const+double+*p)+%7B%0A++v4df+retval+%3D+%7Bp%5B0%5D,+p%5B1%5D,+p%5B2%5D,+p%5B3%5D%7D%3B%0A++return+retval%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%23include+%3Cimmintrin.h%3E%0A%0Av4df+load_4_doubles_intel(const+double+*p)+%7B+return+_mm256_loadu_pd(p)%3B+%7D%0A%0Av4df+avx_constant()+%7B+return+_mm256_setr_pd(+1.0,+2.0,+3.0,+4.0+)%3B+%7D%0A')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3) so you can look at the asm with various compile options and compiler versions.

```
typedef double v4df __attribute__((vector_size(4 * sizeof(double))));

#include <immintrin.h>

// note the return types.  gcc6.1 compiles with no warnings, even at -Wall -Wextra
v4df load_4_doubles_intel(const double *p) { return _mm256_loadu_pd(p); }
    vmovupd ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rdi]   # tmp89,* p
    ret

v4df avx_constant() { return _mm256_setr_pd( 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 ); }
    vmovapd ymm0, YMMWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
    ret
```

**If the args to `_mm_set*` intrinsics aren't compile-time constants, the compiler will do the best it can to make efficient code to get all the elements into a single vector**.  It's usually best to do that rather than writing C that stores to a tmp array and loads from it, because that's not always the best strategy.  (Store-forwarding failure on multiple narrow stores forwarding to a wide load costs an extra ~10 cycles (IIRC) of latency on top of the usual store-forwarding delay.  If your `double`s are already in registers, it's usually best to just shuffle them together.)

---

See also [Is it possible to cast floats directly to __m128 if they are 16 byte alligned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11759791/is-it-possible-to-cast-floats-directly-to-m128-if-they-are-16-byte-alligned/11766098#11766098) for a list of the various intrinsics for getting a single scalar into a vector.  The [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki has links to Intel's manuals, and their intrinsics finder.

---

#### Load/store GNU C vectors without Intel intrinsics:

I'm not sure how you're "supposed" to do that.  [This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18199605/better-way-to-load-vectors-from-memory-clang) suggests casting a pointer to the memory you want to load, and using a vector type like `typedef char __attribute__ ((vector_size (16),aligned (1))) unaligned_byte16;`  (note the `aligned(1)` attribute).

You get a segfault from `*(v4df *)a` because presumably `a` isn't aligned on a 32-byte boundary, but you're using a vector type that does assume natural alignment.  (Just like `__m256d` if you dereference a pointer to it instead of using load/store intrinsics to communicate alignment info to the compiler.)

Comment: Using attribute aligned seems like the normal way to load/store vectors in unaligned memory.

Comment: And that's even how gcc implements _mm256_loadu_pd now ;-) https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/gcc/config/i386/avxintrin.h?revision=239889&view=markup#l868

Answer (score 1):

You can use the equivalent intrinsics from gcc for x86: __builtin_ia32_loadupd256 (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Built-in-Functions.html#x86-Built-in-Functions).

So something like:

```
typedef double v4df __attribute__((vector_size(4 * sizeof(double))));

void vector_copy(double *a, v4df *v)
{
    *v = __builtin_ia32_loadupd256(a);
}
```

Comment: That's not portable to non-x86 platforms.  I just realized that's what the OP is doing.

Comment: @PeterCordes: You are right, I've added a note that this is for x86 (which is what I thought OP wanted).  Your answer is still better though.

Comment: Let me know if you come across a platform-independent way to write vector loads/stores with GNU C vector extensions.  I find it super-weird that there isn't a portable aligned / unaligned load/store builtin, only the platform-specific builtins.  Maybe you are supposed to pointer-cast and dereference?  Anyway, upvoted your answer for pointing out the GNU C builtin that `_mm256_loadu_pd` is implemented on top of.

Comment: Please don't use those builtins. The only advantage over intrinsics is that you don't need a #include. But it may be removed from gcc in the future.

Answer (score -2):

If you don't need to get a copy of a, use a pointer instead (see v_ptr in example). If you need a copy, use memmove (see v_copy)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef double vector __attribute__((vector_size(4 * sizeof(double))));

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  double a[4] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0};
  vector *v_ptr;
  vector v_copy;

  v_ptr = (vector*)&a;
  memmove(&v_copy, a, sizeof(a));

  printf("a[0] = %f // v[0] = %f // v_copy[0] = %f\n", a[0], (*v_ptr)[0], v_copy[0]);
  printf("a[2] = %f // v[2] = %f // v_copy[0] = %f\n", a[2], (*v_ptr)[2], v_copy[2]);
  return 0;
}
```

output:

```
a[0] = 1.000000 // v[0] = 1.000000 // v_copy[0] = 1.000000
a[2] = 3.000000 // v[2] = 3.000000 // v_copy[0] = 3.000000
```

Comment: can you show the output of `gcc -S` which shows whether the compiler did separate copies or used the SSE instructions?

Comment: My assembly is rusty and I am in a mac using clang, but you should be able to build the example above to verify.  You can split these into two files, one with c_ptr and one with c_copy and check. On my machine, when I compile with -O3, both of the examples compile to the same .s file but that is likely because the optimizer realizes that I am not modifying v_copy so it optimizes the memmove away.