# Get uint64_t out of __m128 intrinsic?

Tags: sse, simd, intrinsics

I can use `_mm_set_epi64` to store two `uint64_t`s into a `__m128` intrinsic. But hunting around, I see various ways to get the values back out: There's `reinterpret_cast` (and it's evil twin C-style casts), it's sibling `union { __m128; uint64[2]; };` and `memcpy`, there's accessing fields of `__m128`. There's `__m128i _mm_load_si128(__m128i *p);`, but I'm not seeing a `_mm_get_*` function. Am I missing something? If there's a `_mm_set_epi64` then there must be a non-cast way to get the `uint64_t`s back out, right? (Otherwise why would they bother providing `_mm_set_epi64`?)

I see [Get member of __m128 by index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12624466/get-member-of-m128-by-index) but the "correct answer" has a broken link and implies there's a `load` function, but all the `load`s I see map `__m128` to `__m128`. Shouldn't there be a `void _mm_get_epi64(__m128, uint64_t* outbuf)`?

Comment: I believe what you want is `_mm_extract_epi64`.

Comment: I see, so given `__int64 _mm_extract_epi64 (__m128i a, const int imm8)` it would be `uint64_t x = static_cast<uint64_t>(_mm_extract_epi64(a, 0))`.

Comment: Looks like it. Give it a try. If it works, post an answer and accept it.

Comment: Do you actually have a `__m128` (4 floats), or a `__m128i` (integer)?  The Q&A you linked is about getting a `float` element out of a `__m128`, and is considering runtime-variable indices.

Comment: On https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide you'll find `__int64 _mm_cvtsi128_si64x(__m128i)` to get the low 64 bits, otherwise you need to shuffle or use SSE4.1 `pextrq` (`_mm_extract_epi64`).

Comment: Or if you just want to store the whole vector together, there's `_mm_storeu_si128( (__m128i*)outbuf, vec )`.  And yes that is strict-aliasing safe as part of the intrinsics API.

Comment: [SSE: Difference between \_mm\_load/store vs. using direct pointer access](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11034302) shows how things are normally done if you want to store whole vectors.  [How to extract bytes from an SSE2 \_\_m128i structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39884960) shows how to get separate `uint64_t` halves out, if that's what you want.